# ASP.NET Hidden fields data only available in a postback? why?

Tags: .net-4.0, webforms, hidden-field, client-side-data

According to [MSDN hidden fields section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx),

> In order for hidden-field values to be available during page processing, you must submit the page using an HTTP POST command. If you use hidden fields and a page is processed in response to a link or an HTTP GET command, the hidden fields will not be available.

If I add a HiddenField control at design time and set a value in it at design time or in the Init event in ASP.NET, why would I not be able to read/process the value when a page is first requested?

Comment: Did you try accessing the *control* values? You should see the value is available, IIRC (whatever the default is or whatever you have set it to prior to that). I believe this just says that hidden field data isn't sent from the client->server *in* a GET request. ASP.NET revolves around (re)creating controls as the primary mechanism to resume state.

Comment: How are you trying to read the value? When you look at the source of the page in the browser, do you see your hidden field value there?

Comment: @pst I didn't actually try coding and accessing the value, rather I'm following along in my book and saw this and was confused.

Answer (score 0):

How have you defined your hidden field?

You need to make hidden field as runat="server" like this:

```
<input id="something" type="hidden" value="something that is hidden" runat="server" />
```

Then you will be able to access this field on server even if it is Get request.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Response.Write(string.Format("{0} came from hidden field", something.Value));
}
```